# How to download video from this link using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

I want a button or link that can download or save the video from this type of link.

I am try this code but when i click on the link it Doesn't save the video to device but open the HTML5 video play.

> `<a href="https://rr4---sn-gwpa-pmjz.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1645511732&ei=1C8UYom5FM_hhwaks43wAg&ip=44.201.92.140&id=o-ADrMmRDRPsO5co_3WapfdhpNmpy-aI0as8aimBEQjBQq&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&ns=kLaa53VRRBZK3BdiZax7kSwG&cnr=14&ratebypass=yes&dur=2264.200&lmt=1611181733718538&fexp=24001373,24007246&c=WEB&txp=5535432&n=O38Bzkrt7cdpAQ&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Ccnr%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgJ_Xr0KgAgeaggpUHe4w2PVpJW-JLpXvgIRR6xAQ0G8sCIGQt4ioUXn3fFc2vxcW_JvBjcgcib-4jUPIFVRPPThGa&redirect_counter=1&rm=sn-p5qeer7s&req_id=e8aad143a0eba3ee&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mh=Bb&mip=2409:4051:4e9b:59a7:9de2:5b9:ce83:ae30&mm=31&mn=sn-gwpa-pmjz&ms=au&mt=1645489725&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=48&lsparams=ipbypass,mh,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAIgzEczDyvfbp0AiKfOuTbBJc6NiRoFMCOkb7MaXSwRUAiEA4jiQLlLTaHMYV4NdBqw8BgXpBjNx8qxfUM3CY8KA07Q%3D" download="myvideo.mp4"`

Can someone tell me the the correct way to do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Downloading these videos worked with download.js. You need to make a XMLHTTP request to the video to get the data, and then use the function For more documentation, look on [the download.js GitHub page.](https://github.com/rndme/download)